# IntelliJ Editor - Error Cannot run program - Change java compiler path

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Previously I have installed with Java 15 version.

Recently I have **uninstalled java 15** and **installed the java 1.8 version**.

IntelliJ not automatically not detect the 1.8 version and still looking for java 15 version. So I am getting the below error.

[image]

I changed `File> Build,Execution,Deployment> Java Compiler>` Project bytecode version: 1.8. However, I can't change the Module language level and Project language level to 1.8 because there's not option for that. I still get the same error below.

Someone help me, how to change the compiler path in the IntelliJ Editor.

Comment: Make sure the file exists in that location and try adding the jdk to path. If all else fails, you should be able to download open-jdk-15 from project-structure > sdk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Java Compiler path** is able to change using `File -> Project Structure -> SDK's` and edit the path as java 1.8 jdk path.

[image]